# background-image: url() works when all files on desktop but not with files in their folders

Tags: html, css, background-image

When using the background-image url() to set a full cover background image I have encountered what seems like a glitch that I can't figure out. When I have the index.html file, the main.css file and the image file on my desktop the image shows up fine in the browser. However, when I move the .jpg to an imgs folder and the .css file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zubX4.png)to the css folder the image won't appear in the browser.

The code is exactly copied from W3, so I'm thinking it must be a problem with my folder structure, but I can't see it. I've never seen this issue before. Thanks in advance!

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </body>
</html>


body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url("/imgs/ocean.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Try with: background-image: url("../imgs/ocean.jpg"); @dinarrene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax instead: Because `./` refers to the current folder, `../` refers to the parent directory and that one should be used.

```
background-image: url("../imgs/ocean.jpg");
```

Comment: No use just giving the answer, explain why we use the dots. This person is just starting out with programming. Two dots `../` means go up a level from the current folder. Single dot `./`, means relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

use pixel in height and width and check the path of background-image

```
.bg {
  background-image: url("imgs/ocean.jpg");
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using / at the start of the path will use the root directory which in this case is C:

Use this instead:

```
background-image: url("../imgs/ocean.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

`background-image: url("../imgs/ocean.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers here are correct, they don't do a very good job at explaining 'why'.

`background-image: url("../imgs/ocean.jpg");` should work for you.

Heres why:

In directory paths, two dots at the start of the path `../` means go up a level relative to the current working directory (i.e. if used in your index.html file, the search will start from wherever that is). You can go up multiple levels, i.e. `../../../` to go up three levels. A single dot `./` at the start of the path means follow the path, starting from ***here***.
A single slash `/` at the start of the path will use the root directory which on Windows is usually your `C:` drive, or on Linux/Unix/Mac is the very start of the file tree.

Answer (score 0):

Used the below code in main.css file, it is working:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.bg {
  **background-image:** url("../imgs/ocean.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```